# Xcode Admob Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'UniformTypeIdentifiers'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

Google said I needed to update my AdMob SDK to 8.1 now I get these errors:

```
Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'UniformTypeIdentifiers'
Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKOverlay
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKOverlayAppConfiguration
```

I have already tried all the solutions to all related answers on StackOverflow

- Increased iOS Deployment Target
- Clean Build / Restart Xcode
- rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Deleted all frameworks and add them again
- Link Binary With Libraries has all 6 required frameworks
- Added -ObjC to Other Linker Flags
- Added build setting LD_VERIFY_BITCODE NO

Xcode 12, Swift project
I am not using CocoaPods and don't want to.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#manual_download

Note that these problems don't exist on AdMob 7, only the new version.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I switched back to admob 7 for a while, while they fix things and actually make updated documentation. They don't let you download admob 7 but luckily I still had it in my trash bin and was able to recover it. Now admob is on version 8.8 and it works for me.